# How to prevent increase a field in Django

Tags: python, django, web, backend

i have a model in django called products. that have a field called star that store my score of products (from 0 to 5) and i want to not allow to increase more that 5 (or even be negative number).

`star = models.IntegerField(default=0, max_length=5)`

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
    {% with ''|center:item.star as range %}
        {% for _ in range %}
            <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
</div>
```

what can i do?

for example if one of my products have star field with 7
it show 7 star in product page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/) to do that for you.

```py
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

star = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])
```